# jQuery: ajax content not loading on certain computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have a very strange problem with a Javascript function:

```
function changeContent(url, id) {
  jQuery('#'+id).load(url);
}
```

As you can see the function is not very complicated. It simply loads the content of a url into an element.

But it just doesn' t work on a computer of a friend no matter which browser he uses.
In Fiddler I can see that the request works fine but the content of the div just doesn' t change.

Any idea what I / he can do?

Comment: In such case, you should check your friend browser that javascript is `enable` or `disabled`.

Comment: On your friend's machine, can you see the response come back from the server and if s/he has javascript enabled?  Is it an HTML response that comes back from the server?

Comment: tells them to enable javascript

Comment: have you checked it in third computer?

Comment: Javascript is activated and he gets the right HTML code as response to the request (checked with Fiddler) but somehow the page isn't updated. This happens in every browser he tried.

Comment: Can you show your page? Hard to diagnose without any more information as the function is fine. It could be that your jquery script is being called locally from your machine for example.

Comment: maybe caching problem if the page is not updated @Michael

Comment: @Michael Can you post the link to your fiddle?  Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All works, your function is correct:

```
$('#test').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/Resources.js'); // correct

$('#test').load('http://doc.jsfiddle.net/'); // Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
// http://doc.jsfiddle.net/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by 
// Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here is sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/AG9nf/

Are you put same domain into url attribute?
​

Comment: Good point about same domain constraint. It might explain why the behavior is different on the two computers. Side comment: the example that loads a js file is a little bit strange...

Comment: localhost and 192.160.0.100 ?  :D

Comment: Thank you Boris, I figured it out now. The problem was that the script loads the pages from http://www.abcd.com and my friend accessed the pages on http://abcd.com somehow (I made a htaccess "redirect"). By adding www. it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code looks too simple, as usually you don't want to load a whole page (including head and body) inside another. Instead, use a selector to target a fragment of the page.

[See the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) about loading page fragments.